# Graphical tablet detected but still displaying "no signal"

Tags: display, tablet, wacom, graphics-tablet

I recently received a Graphical Tablet (Wacom Cintiq 16) that I have been trying to get to work on my Ubuntu.

My system is a dual boot Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and the tablet has been working perfectly on Windows.

On Ubuntu, when I plug the tablet it / turn it on, it briefly displays the quick selection menu that appears for new monitors (extend display / mirror / one only etc...), but then all it does is revert my settings to their defaults (zoom 100%, when I have my monitors set to zoom 200%). After a bit the tablet goes to **"no signal"**.

I have two monitors:

- my built in laptop screen (1080p)
- an external 4k monitor, plugged on a thunderbolt port.

The tablet itself is plugged on USB3 port and the laptop HDMI port.

I tried to make sure I have the proper drivers and tools, so I followed this guide: https://ragnarb.com/configuring-wacom-cintiq-13hd-with-ubuntu-14-04/

And this: https://linuxwacom.github.io, where I installed the kernel drive and the `libwacom` tool. The X driver was already installed.

It seems the tablet is detected:

`$ libwacom-list-local-devices`

```
devices:
- name: 'Wacom Cintiq 16'
  bus: 'usb'
  vid: '0x056a'
  pid: '0x03ae'
  nodes: 
  - /dev/input/event257
```

and

`$ xsetwacom --list devices`

```
Wacom Cintiq 16 Pen stylus          id: 29  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Cintiq 16 Pen eraser          id: 30  type: ERASER
```

Also, when plugged in and turned on I now have a new tab in my settings:

[image: wacom menu]

But I played around with the settings to no avail (for example Calibrate brings out the calibration screen on my external monitor)

I imagine I would expect the tablet to also appear as an additional monitor, but it does not:

[image: displays]

Furthermore, when I run `xrandr` I get:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 5760 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected 1920x1080+3840+862 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080    144.03*+  60.08    60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93
   ...
   320x175       85.27  
DP-1 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 525mm x 295mm
   3840x2160     60.00*+
   ...
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

So it almost looks like while it gets the Wacom info through USB, the HDMI part isn't performing as expected.

Here are my system information:

[image: ubuntu]

Any idea what could be causing this issue?

Comment: @guiverc I wrote Ubuntu 20 as a shorthand for the full version (20.04.3 LTS) as visible in the last picture. Didn't know there was a Ubuntu Core 20 too, so I'll edit for clarity sake

Comment: Ubuntu has products that use 20; eg. Ubuntu Core 20.  They are different systems to the *year.month* format which is why 20 is used (and it's not called 20.04).  Ubuntu has had *year* products since 2016; they are *snap* only (thus no `dpkg` or `apt` like commands); have 10 years supported lives (equiv. to LTS + ESM included), apps run *confined* (no access to root file-system; very different to 20.04 systems) etc..   20 != 20.04